# Delete (almost) duplicate values between two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
Table1:
Columns: Id, name, info, date.

Table2 (temporary): name, info, date.
```

'Id' in table1 is an automatically generated number. I want to delete from Table1 the ones that have the same 'info' and 'date' values as another line in Table2, among the ones that have the same 'name' value in Table1 and Table2.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a subquery which joins the two relations on identical values and then remove those values from your Table1:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (name, value, date) IN (
    SELECT t.name, t.value, t.date
    FROM Table1 AS t
    JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON (t.name = t2.name AND t.value = t2.value AND t.date = t2.date)
)
```

Comment: I've edited my question because it seems like it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Hm. I think the query still does what you're trying To do. If it's not, could you please give an example with sample data?